# I need to get the element id of page 2 and write a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I am trying to write a html page(page1) to hit a url of another page (Pgae2). and get the element id of a dropdown of page 2 to display it selected when I click on a hyperlink of url of page 2 from page1.
Could anyone tell how to implement this?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <body>
      <p><a href="page.aspx" onclick="network();" >link</a></p>
   </body>
</html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> function network()
```

**Js:**

```
{
    var selectednetwork =
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlNetwork").‌​selectedIndex;

    alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlNetwork"));
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("option")[selectednetwork].value == "LAN-AD-EU"); {

        for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
            if (selectObj.options[i].text == LAN - AD - EU) {
                selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does you try so far ?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><a href="page.aspx" onclick="network();" >link</a></p>
</body>
</html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> function network()

Comment: {
  var selectednetwork=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlNetwork").selectedIndex;
alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlNetwork"));
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("option")[selectednetwork].value=="LAN-AD-EU");{
     for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectObj.options[i].text== LAN-AD-EU) {
            selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
  }
}</script>

Comment: This is what I tried

Comment: _"This is what I tried"_ This info should be the part of question, not here in comments. Please revise your question again.

Answer (score 0):

On the page 2 you simply can fetch the ID by document.getElementById("ID") and use it on document.ready . there is nothing to do with page one in your case .

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by using [GET](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method of jQuery.

**For e.g.**

```
$.get('Page2.html', null, function(text){
    alert($(text).find('#name')); //#name is the name of your dropdown of 2nd page
});
```

Comment: I can't do anything on page 2. Page 2 code is inaccessible to me. and its an asp page and this I already tried $.get('page2.aspx').then(function(responseData) {
  //responseData is the contents of the other page. Do whatever you want with it.
  $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlNetwork').append(responseData);
});

Comment: You need to provide all this information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected value in localstorage on change event of dropdown like this -

`localStorage.setItem("selectedValue","yourselectedValue");`

and you can access this value from any page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<a>` element, `location.hash`, `.focus()`

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="page2.html#select">click</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <select id="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2" selected>2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        document.querySelector(location.hash).focus();
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/mTXgH7GMBwamwyCGtkms?p=preview